# unset while command if is empty

Tags: php, mysql, recordset

i have a while command after mysql and give me a row but if row is empty i get error 'Undefined variable' code is:

```
$m_list = mysql_query("SELECT
    t2.name,     
    t2.group
    FROM tbl_m_list t1, tbl_mn_list t2
    WHERE t1.user_id = '$uid' AND
    t1.name       = t2.name    AND
    t1.group  = t2.group" );

while ($mrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($m_list)) {
    $mname[] =$mrow['name'];
    $group[] =$mrow['group'];
}
```

and this is number 2 command for calling first command:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($mname); $i++) {?>
    <div >
        <div >
            <span >job</span>
            <span >name:</span>
            <div ><?php    echo  $mname[$i] ?>          </div>
            <span >daste:</span>
            <div ><?php    echo  $group[$i] ?>      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

give me 'Undefined variable'error for line 4 from command 2 
"mname" 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The variables need to be defined in order to prevent the notice from occurring, otherwise, the variable is only set if `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns any data.

#### Basic solution

Before the `while` loop, define them, like so:

```
$mname = array();
$group = array();

while ($mrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($m_list)) {
// ...
```

#### Better solution

Use the `while` loop instead using *another* loop and storing the data in two other variables. This is a cleaner solution as you're not iterating over the data twice.

```
while ($mrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($m_list)) { ?>
<div ><div ><span >job</span>
        <span >name:</span>
            <div ><?php    echo  $mrow['name'] ?>          </div>
        <span >daste:</span>
            <div ><?php    echo  $mrow['group'] ?>      </div>
    </div></div>
<?php } ?>
```

*Note: Try to refactor this code so that you aren't using `mysql_*` functions (use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead), as they have been removed from PHP7 and onwards.*

Comment: i do try 'while ($mrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($m_list)) { ?>' but give me this error:   mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in ... ! if i want to use mysqli Just have to add one "i" commands have no other difference?thanks

Comment: Is your query returning a resource? You could wrap the `while` with an `if` to check the query succeeded and returned a resource.